# Continuity of Infimum function on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Suppose $F$ is a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f(x)= \inf_{y \in F}|x-y|$, where $|x-y|$ is the usual Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that $f$ is continuous and that $f(x)=0$ iff $x \in F$.

Thoughts:

We want to show that given some $ \epsilon > 0$, for $a \in F$ we can find some $\delta >0$ such that $|a-b|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(a)-f(b)|< \epsilon$.

Comment: This has been asked before.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Would you be able to post a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** One direction is trivial, if $x\in F$ then $|x-x|$ is in the set over which you take the infimum. The other direction is easier to prove using sequences. Recall that $x\in F$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_n\in F$ such that $\lim x_n=x$, use the assumption that $\inf\{|x-y|:y\in F\}=0$ to show there is such sequence $x_n\in F$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a set, and draw the function. What do you notice?

**Hint:**  Use the triangle inequality.

**Hint:** You can use $\delta = \epsilon$.